# Should there be a mezuzah on a room that has baby diapers?

Tags: mezuzah, bathroom

If there is a general purpose room (like a bedroom) wherein a child's soiled diapers are often disposed of, does that room take on the status of tashmish she'aino shel kavod - a room who's use is not dignified ([Yoreh Deah 286:4](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch/Yoreh_Deah/286)), and therefore becomes exempt from mezuzah?

Comment: +1 for an interesting question! I imagine that you would want to differentiate between a room in which such diapers are habitually disposed of and one set aside for that purpose... Otherwise, would this not be similar to having a mezuzah on the door of a child's bedroom, when the child habitually soils the bed?

Comment: @ShimonbM to clarify, my understanding is that there is no mezuzah on a bathroom because that room is designated for 'non-kavod' activities. I'm asking about a room where a child is normally changed and where the diapers are regularly disposed of before being taken out of the house. I want to know if a room like that has the same status l'gabei mezuzah. As far as I know there is no room designated for children to soil themselves.

Comment: I don't have a source right now, but baby diapers are not the same category as non-baby excrement.

Answer (score 1):

The Ben Ish Chai sefer 2 Parshas Ki Tovah halacha 20 says that if one goes in and out and uses the place like a cattle room (as long as it is not disgusting) then it has a status of a room. A room where women wash themselves it would seem they don't need a *mezuzah* but if there is a door and it is locked during use then one is obligated in *mezuzah* from the outside.

A bathroom, or bathhouse, tannery, or mikvah are not a dwelling of honor and are *patur* (exempt).

It seems that there is an in-between type case which if one uses the place in an *kovadik* (honorable) way sometimes it is fine, but if it is always dirty then it is *patur*.

This is all speculation, please read it inside. I brought this as source because it seems to answer your question, but it can be debated.

Comment: I'm going to review the source. I wasn't clear from your answer how this resolves the questions directly.

Comment: See Aruch Hashulchan 286:5,6,7 for more info.

Comment: Sam, I found a relevant entry in the [aruch hashulchan 286:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14244&st=&pgnum=373). Would you like to incorporate into your answer? Otherwise I will post it separately as an answer